# How can I put an array of hashes, within a hash in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Perl have a very nice documentation of [combinations of arrays and hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES), but I can't find one for Ruby.

When I try

```
data = {
  "key" => "value",
  [{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]
}

p data
```

I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
test.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are declaring a hash and set it to the `data` variable.
Therefore, ruby expects the syntax:

```
key => value
```

**But your second element is not in this form**, it is only a value (an Array), there is no key associated ! I don't know about Perl, but Ruby does not allow it.
You could do :

```
data = {
   "key" => "value",
   "key2" => [{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A Hash has to be key value pair. However your second element is not:

```
[{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]
```

It should be something like:

```
data = {
  "key" => "value",
  "array" => [{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]
}
```

As you can see I added a new key `"array"` which has value `[{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]`. Since this  fits the Hash definition there will be no error. You can name your key anything as long as you have one.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you meant this by "combination of arrays and hashes"

```
data = [
  { "key" => "value"},
  [{"name"=>"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]
]
```

Here it's an array of two elements:  a hash and an array of hashes. Whether it's something you want or not - I can't tell (from your question).

Comment: interesting perspective. That didn't at all occurred to me :)

Comment: I agree. I edited the question title to align with @shivam interpretation, although this one is nice, too.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you have the hash inside an array? Is it necessary?
could be because the array has no key, try this

```
data = {
  "key":"value",
  array:[hash:{"name":"abc", "number"=>898, "email"=>"abc@xyz.com"}]
}
```